# Create environment that draws a rule next to the text

Tags: formatting, environments, memoir, rules

In my document it often happens that I ask a question, which I mark by making the text bold. I'd like to additionally place a 2-3mm grey rule to either the left-hand or the right-hand side of the text as shown in this example:

[image]

Is it possible to make this into an environment so I can merely write `\question{....}`? Currently I haven't decided whether I want this rule to the left or the right side of the question, but would like to see how this can be done.

Here is my MWE so far, which has everything beside the rule:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\textbf{This is a question?}

And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the tcolorbox package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use the `tcolorbox` package and apply a `\newtcbox` that draws a `borderline west` with some specified colour left to the text (which is 'west' in `TikZ` language).

If the rule should appear right, use `borderline east`. The first `3mm` indicate the width of the rule, the second `-3mm` refer to a shifting to the left side.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{questionbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,
  colback=white,
  fontupper=\bfseries,
  left=0pt,
  nobeforeafter,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  borderline west={3mm}{-3mm}{gray},
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\questionbox{This is a question?}

And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Using a `tcolorbox` environment in order to allow for line wrapping and `breakable` to break over pages.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{questionbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  frame hidden,
  colback=white,
  fontupper=\bfseries,
  left=0pt,
  nobeforeafter,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  borderline west={3mm}{-3mm}{gray},
  breakable,
  #1
}



\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{questionbox}
  This is a question \blindtext?
\end{questionbox}

And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error `I do not know the key '/tcb/borderline west',`. Is my version of pgfplot too old?

Comment: @BillyJean: `pgfplot` seems unrelated. The `tcolorbox` version that adds the `borderline` feature was released in late October, 2014

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. If the question is very long though, then it doesn't break the sentence but simply writes outside the page. Is it possible to break the question and extend the rule accordingly?

Comment: @BillyJean: Add `breakable` to the option list of the `questionbox`

Comment: I added `breakable` to the list of options (`..., breakable, ...`), but it didn't make a difference. I tried adding both at the beginning and the end, but made no difference

Comment: @BillyJean: See the update at the end of my answer, please

Comment: Hi my dear friend. Hi, and good work.+1

Answer (score 1):

A simple command using only the `xcolor` package, and an environment based on the `leftbar` environment from `framed`, which can break across pages:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\myquestion[1]{\par\noindent\llap{\color{Gainsboro}\rule[-0.25ex]{0.5em}{2ex}\hspace{\marginparsep}}\textbf{#1}\par}

\newenvironment{Question}{\par\noindent%
\def\FrameCommand{\hspace{-1.1em}{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 0.5em}\hspace{0.6em}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}\bfseries\strut\hspace{-1.36\parindent}}%
{\endMakeFramed\vspace{-\topsep}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\myquestion{This is a question?}

And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. And here is the answer. 

\begin{Question}
This is a very long question?
Is this indeed a very long question?
\end{Question}

And here is a short answer.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is also nice. This automatically breaks the sentence if it is too long, but doesn't extend the rule. Do I have to do that manually?

Comment: Ah! That is a different problem. I'll post another possibility in a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that is a nice solution. Is it possible to align the rule to the right of the sentence as well?

Comment: Do you mean two rules both on the left and the right side, or a single rule on the right?

Comment: Just a single rule to the right